# Matrix $A=B+C$ with $B$ symmetric and $C$ antisymmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetry

I am stumped on a question and am looking for some guidance on how to get it done.

The problem gives you:

$x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}9&-4&-2 \\-9&6&-3 \\10&-3&9\end{bmatrix}$

$x_1 = x_2 + x_3$.

$x_2$ is a symmetric matrix and $x_3$ is an antisymmetric matrix.

That is that part that confuses me. The only thing Ive gotten is that the $x_2$ has the $9,6,9$ on the diagonal and $x_3$ has $0$ for its diagonal. Can anyone help me down the right path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any square matrix $A$ over a field $\Bbb F$ with $\text{char} \; \Bbb F \ne 2$, note that $A_+ = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$ is symmetric, and $A_- = \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)$ is skew-symmetric, where $A^T$ is the transpose of the matrix $A$.  Furthermore, $A = A_+ + A_-$, so we can simply apply these formulas to the given matrix $x_1$ and we see that we can take

$x_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 9 & -\frac{13}{2} & 4 \\ -\frac{13}{2}  & 6 & -3 \\ 4 & -3 & 9 \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$

and

$x_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{5}{2} & -6 \\ -\frac{5}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 6 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$.

Incidentally, the decomposition $A = A_+ + A_-$ is unique; to see this just write $A = B_+ + B_-$ as another symmetric-plus-skew-symmetric representation of $A$.  Then $A_+ - B_+ = A_- - B_-$, and since the left-hand side is symmetric while the right-hand side is skew, they are both zero.  (Note that $A^T = A \; \text{and} \ A^T = -A \Rightarrow A = -A \Rightarrow A = 0$.)

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 6):

Note that for any square matrix $A$, we have 
$$A=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)+\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$$
where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$. Note that 
$\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is symmetric because
$$\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)^T=\frac{1}{2}(A^T+A).$$
Similarly, $\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$ is antisymmetric because 
$\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)^T=-\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$.

Therefore, in your case when $x_1=\begin{bmatrix}9&-4&-2 \\-9&6&-3 \\10&-3&9\end{bmatrix}$, we have 
$$x_2=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_1^T)\mbox{ and }x_3=\frac{1}{2}(x_1-x_1^T).$$

Comment: Thank you for the help. I messed up the bottom -4 when it should have been a -9. Would that affect anything?

Comment: I see. The idea is the same. But you have $x_2=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_1^T)=\frac{1}{2}(\begin{bmatrix}9&-4&-2 \\-9&6&-3 \\10&-3&9\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}9&-4&-2 \\-9&6&-3 \\10&-3&9\end{bmatrix}^T)=\frac{1}{2}(\begin{bmatrix}9&-4&-2 \\-9&6&-3 \\10&-3&9\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}9&-9&10 \\-4&6&-3 \\-2&-3&9\end{bmatrix})=...$

Comment: That makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 4):

To continue, we have $$x_1=x_2+x_3$$
and $$x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}9&-4&-2 \\-9&6&-3 \\10&-3&9\end{bmatrix} \quad
x_2 = \begin{bmatrix}9&a&b \\a&6&c \\b&c&9\end{bmatrix} \quad
x_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0&d&e \\-d&0&f \\-e&-f&0\end{bmatrix}$$
for $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{R}$.

So we have simultaneous equations such as $$-4=a+d \quad \text{and} \quad -9=a-d$$ which, when we solve, imply $a=-\frac{13}{2}$ and $d=\frac{5}{2}$.

Now consider the simultaneous equations $$-3=c+f \quad \text{and} \quad -3=c-f$$ and $$-2=b+e \quad \text{and} \quad 10=b-e.$$

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions I understand how you did that. Although I made a mistake in my top matrix. The bottom -4 should be a -9.

Comment: Updated; it's the same idea though.